# Disable CloudKit debugging logs

Tags: ios, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I am using a `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` for the database in my iOS app. By default it seems to log all events to the console, I am assuming for debugging purposes. These messages look like this:

```
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitExportContext processAnalyzedHistoryInStore:inManagedObjectContext:error:]_block_invoke_4(201): Finished processing analyzed history with 1 metadata objects to create, 0 deleted rows without metadata.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitExporter exportIfNecessary]_block_invoke_2(137): <PFCloudKitExporter: 0x282a785f0>: Found 2 objects needing export.
CoreData: warning: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitExporter exportOperationFinished:withSavedRecords:deletedRecordIDs:operationError:](384): Modify records finished: (
    etc...
```

They are constant and are getting in the way of other debug messages, is there any way to disable them?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I use these two arguments to reduce the output (Arguments passed on launch):

disable CoreData debug output:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 0
```

disable CloudKit debug output

```
-com.apple.CoreData.CloudKitDebug 0
```

[image]

Products > Scheme > Edit scheme

Comment: With these settings, you can still see some significant CloudKit log entires in Console.  Just search for CK or your app id.  I am using these with  -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1